# How to Set ubuntu Auto power on off everday

Tags: power-management

How can i set automatic power on and power off everyday, time schedule on ubuntu.
Such as everyday my ubuntu power on at 9:00 AM and power off 6:00 PM
Plz anybody help me.

Comment: look here for possible answers https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1776541

Comment: I have the same question about a power / suspend schedule for Ubuntu. Here are some related posts: https://askubuntu.com/a/1009688/48214 and https://askubuntu.com/q/144832/48214

Comment: You could suspend for a while [with `rtcwake`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/185481/209677)

Answer (score 0):

you can change your setting of your BIOS to set your PC power off in specific time or you can use some application.
these two link will help you:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

http://gnome-schedule.sourceforge.net/

sorry for my poor English

Comment: Please kindly put down how it's done in case the links go dead