# Sleep & Wakeup Schedule | Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

Tags: suspend, cron, rtc

I've been looking for solutions to have my computer go to sleep at 1am EST and wakeup at 6pm EST every day. Thus far I've been unsuccessful.

I tried using rtcwake and cronjobs as well as the script here:

[Automatically Resume from Sleep / Standby / Suspend | Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=938533&page=4)

Even other forums I couldn't make it work.

Would really appreciate help.

P.s. I have disk encryption enabled so I can't hybernate.

Comment: What is the make and model of your computer?

Comment: Can you manually suspend/resume your computer via menu/keyboard/power button?

Answer (score 10):

## **From terminal :**

**Suspend and wake up after 60 sec :**

```
sudo rtcwake -m disk -s 60
```

**Suspend and wake up today 16.00**

```
sudo rtcwake -m no -l -t "$(date -d 'today 16:00:00' '+%s')"
```

**Suspend and wake up tommorow 10.00 :**

```
sudo rtcwake -m no -l -t $(date +%s -d 'tomorrow 10:00')
```

**Suspend and wake up specific date and time :**

```
sudo rtcwake -m no -l -t "$(date -d '2017-04-25 16:00:00' '+%s')"
```

**To shutdown for Maintenance use :**

```
sudo shutdown -P +60 "The system is going DOWN to maintenance mode in 60 minutes!"

sudo shutdown -P 22:10 "The system is going DOWN to maintenance mode at 22:10!"
```

---

## **Using Autopoweroff :**

**Download Autopoweroff:**

```
wget https://github.com/deragon/autopoweroff/releases/download/3.0.0/autopoweroff-3.0.0-1.noarch.deb
```

**Install Autopoweroff:**

```
sudo dpkg -i autopoweroff-3.0.0-1.noarch.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

[image: autopoweroff]
[image: autopoweroff2]

Comment: Thank An0n. I'm not sure why but that application doesn't seem to be working see configuration: http://prntscr.com/ijm11d

At 1:37pm EST I configured it as seen in that image. Hit "Save" and then "Quit".  It's now  2:09 EST and nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: It uses UTC time.

Comment: it went to sleep on time but failed to wake up. I had this same problem when I used rtcwake and cronjobs together.

Comment: You must change that in your bios settings in the power settings should be something like "Auto-power-on"

Comment: Please mark the Answer as Accepted if it solved your issue. So people know the question is answered. Thx in advance.

Comment: No luck with the power settings in my bios. I'm using an Z370 Aorus Gaming 5 chipset. I tested out 3 different features. Also tried switching to RTC wake but that wouldn't even put my computer to sleep, specifically : sudo rtcwake -m no -l -t "$(date -d 'today 16:00:00' '+%s')".

I tested the time with UTC and EST and gave the system 10 minutes to to detect the new cronjob.

Comment: I got a write error when I used it with "-m disk" (I think this is hybrid sleep) but it worked with "-m mem" (suspend to RAM).

Answer (score 4):

The script you are following is overly complicated. A simpler method is described [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/121241/how-to-make-your-linux-pc-wake-from-sleep-automatically/).

Before a full implementation of 1am sleep and 6am wake, you can do a simple 10 second test:

```
sudo rtcwake -m mem -s 10 && firefox
```

This test will ensure suspending to RAM actually works. Upon resuming `firefox` is automatically started up.

Rather than messing around with UTC, have your `rtcwake` command called from `cron` at 1am and wake up `18000` seconds later. Your cron table entry would look something like this:

```
0 1 * * *  sh /usr/sbin/rtcwake -m mem -s 18000 >> /home/Me/SuspendResume.log 2>&1
```

There is no need for `sudo` prefix because `cron` runs with sudo privileges.

Replace `Me` with your user name. Check the file `SuspendResume.log` for cron messages periodically and whenever there is a problem. `2>&1` option redirects error messages to the `.log` file.

## Caveats

- RTC stands for real-time clock. rtcwake uses your computer’s hardware clock, which you can set in your BIOS, to determine when your computer will wake up. If you’re using an old computer with a dying CMOS battery that can’t keep the clock running properly, this won’t work.
- If sleep, suspend to RAM, or hibernate don’t work properly with your Linux system – perhaps because Linux doesn’t have the drivers to make them work properly with your hardware – this may not work.
- Be careful when setting a laptop to automatically wake at a specific time. You wouldn’t want it waking up, running, and overheating or running down its battery in a laptop bag.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted my computer to sleep at 11:59pm local time each night and wake up each morning at 9:00am.

And I know that cronjobs can help with this.

I used a tool (such as https://cron.help/#59_23_*_*_*) to show me that the correct syntax for the go-to-sleep schedule that I want is `59 23 * * *`.

And then I needed to calculate how many seconds the sleep should last: 9:00am is 9 hours + 1 minute after 11:59pm. (9 * 60 + 1) * 60 = 32460 seconds

So I ran `crontab -e` to edit the cron jobs via vim and added these 2 lines:

```
# inspired by https://askubuntu.com/a/1348204/48214 and https://askubuntu.com/a/1012051/48214 and https://itectec.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-automatically-sleep-and-wake-up-at-specific-times/
59 23 * * * /usr/sbin/rtcwake -m disk -s 32460 >> /code/cron.log 2>&1
```

And I saved the file.

---

The steps above will work for most people on most computers, but unfortunately I realized from [this quick test](https://askubuntu.com/a/1012051/48214) that my particular ancient computer has problems with `rtcwake`.

So instead, what I'm using now only suspends my computer on a schedule, and I haven't figured out how to schedule waking up yet:

```
59 23 * * * echo "$(date) Running /usr/local/bin/systemctl-suspend" >> /code/cron.log && /usr/local/bin/systemctl-suspend >> /code/cron.log 2>&1
```

which I got from https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/642533/48973.